# Responsive Design: Below 768px , my banner images are very stretched. I tried height=auto, but IE9 didn't display them at all then

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Responsive Design: Below 768px , my banner images are very stretched. I tried height=auto, but IE9 didn't display them at all then.

So, how can I make the height not stretch and look decent?

I'm using: Bootstrap 3.1.1, jQuery 1.11, and FlexSlider (the images in question are in a FlexSlider Carousel)

My web page is at:
http://www.amleo.com/

My HTML is:

```
<section class="slider">
    <div class="container White_BG">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
            <!--Slider Start-->
            <div class="flexslider" id="mainslider">
                <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                    <ul class="slides" style="width: 1200%; margin-left: -1514px;">
                        <li class="clone" style="width: 757px; float: left; display: block;">
                            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/Search.aspx?ss=Leonard+Fertilizer" title="Leonard Fertilizer Stakes and Tablets">
                            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/1438_leonard-fertilizer-web.jpg" width="770" height="322" title="Leonard Fertilizer Stakes and Tablets" alt="Leonard Fertilizer Stakes and Tablets">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" style="width: 757px; float: left; display: block;">
                            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/deer/a/84/kc/4G14Pw/" target="_blank" title="Tenex Deer Fencing Sale">
                            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/1441-Deer-Fencing.jpg" width="770" height="322" title="Tenex Deer Fencing Sale" alt="Tenex Deer Fencing Sale">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="width: 757px; float: left; display: block;" class="flex-active-slide">
                            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/polysample/a/29_31/" target="_blank" title="OW Poly Sample">
                            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/1433_ow-plus-web.jpg" width="770" height="322" title="OW Poly Sample" alt="OW Poly Sample">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="width: 757px; float: left; display: block;">
                            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/quickorder.aspx" title="Quick Order Form">
                            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/1441-quick-order-content-web.jpg" width="770" height="322" title="Quick Order Form" alt="Quick Order Form">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="width: 757px; float: left; display: block;">
                            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/Search.aspx?ss=Leonard+Fertilizer" title="Leonard Fertilizer Stakes and Tablets">
                            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/1438_leonard-fertilizer-web.jpg" width="770" height="322" title="Leonard Fertilizer Stakes and Tablets" alt="Leonard Fertilizer Stakes and Tablets">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="clone" style="width: 757px; float: left; display: block;">
                            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/deer/a/84/kc/4G14Pw/" target="_blank" title="Tenex Deer Fencing Sale">
                            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/1441-Deer-Fencing.jpg" width="770" height="322" title="Tenex Deer Fencing Sale" alt="Tenex Deer Fencing Sale">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
                    <li><a class="">1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="flex-active">2</a></li>
                    <li><a>3</a></li>
                    <li><a>4</a></li>
                </ol>
                <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
                    <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                    <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Slider End-->
        </div>
        <!--Side Banner-->
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs visible-lg" style="border:4px;padding-left:0px!important;">
            <a href="http://www.amleo.com/careers/a/66/" title="AM Leonard Careers">
            <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/Career_ad_2014.jpg" width="379" height="321" alt="AM Leonard Careers">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!--End Side Banner-->
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Which image(s), exactly? Try a percentage for width, and don't declare anything for height. If you declare both height and width, it can't be responsive, even with percentages, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

In `flexslider.css` it reads:

```
.flexslider .slides img { ... }
```

It looks like you need to add `height: auto;` and then use javascript to remove the `height` attribute that the slider is applying to the images.

Something along the lines of:

```
jQuery('.slides img').attr('height', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.flexslider .slides img{ width:auto;}
```

If you do not want to stretch an image.